# gnuplot script worked perfectly, but after changing name of the plot data file it doesn't work at all

Tags: gnuplot

I have a gnuplot script that executed perfectly. I did a global change of plot data file name.  Now nothing happens, no png files, no error messages.

Comment: Have you changed the file name in the gnuplot script, too?

Comment: Found my error!  I hadn't run gnuplot in a while and forgotten something.  The "key file" lists all the variables and assigns numbers. However, gnuplot has constraints for variable names and one of them is you can't have underscores ("_"), but you can have hyphens.  The program that generated the plot data file and key file had two variables with underscores in their names.  When I used ExamDiff Pro to compare the key file for the case that had worked with the current key file, I immediately saw the error, fixed it and now my script works perfectly again.

Comment: Just saw choroba's suggestion - yes, I did.  The error was something else (see above).  Thanks anyway

Comment: That is backwards. Gnuplot allows underscores but not hyphens.